# how to run debootstrap for arm64

Tags: arm64, debootstrap, xilinx

I'm trying to install full headless ubuntu on an arm 64 Xilinx system, debootstrap wants to be pointed to a mirror, but I can't find one for arm64
I can already install petalinux on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find it in ubuntu-ports directory

```
debootstrap --arch arm64 focal /mnt http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
```